# ipad mdns/bonjour not responding

Tags: ipad, bonjour, mdns

I am developing an app to get information on network devices.

I have seen two different ipads get into a state where they are not sending out bonjour/mDNS traffic.

I used wireshark and did not see any broadcast traffic from the ipads at all.

I have a bonjour broadcast that other devices were responding to but the two iPads in question did not respond.

After I shut down the ipad and restarted it I was seeing normal bonjour traffic and they responded to my bonjour query just fine.

The iPads had been running for a long time without being shut down.

So, the question is: do iPads get into a funky state after they have been running for a long time where the mDNS service stops working?

Are there other causes for this to happen?

Is there any way to kick it other than shutting down to get it to respond again?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm having a similar issue where the iPad is not responding to mdns broadcasts.

Answer (score 1):

A suggeston, mostly maybe the problem of your progame. Once I met this case. My soultion is like this:
  restart(re alloc) bonjour browse once the program exchanged "backgournd from foreground", of course,stop bonjour browse from "foreground" to "background" firstly. Thus sloved.